# mongoose update a object inside a array of objects

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to add an object in a specific object inside an array of objects.

My model:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "634c0777427df2a5adc17b4c",
        "title": "PROGRAMME TEST",
        "user": {
            "name": "Jérémy",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "profilPicture": "google.fr"
        },
        "exercices": [
            {
                "exercice": "6349563c2e0df123096b7feb",
                "totalSet": 1,
                "rest": "1"
                // add value here 
            },
            {
                "exercice": "634956452e0df123096b7fed",
                "totalSet": 2,
                "rest": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is my query. It does nothing (not even an error):

```js
return this.programModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    $and: [
      {_id: '634c0777427df2a5adc17b4c' }, (program id)
      { exercices: { 'exercices.exercice': "6349563c2e0df123096b7feb" } }, (exercice id want I to add my object)
    ]
  },
  { $push: {"exercices.exercice": {result: result}}},
  { new: true }
);
```

EDIT:

Here is my entire `program.entity.ts` in case it can help.

unfortunately, none of the answers in the comment did work.

As I'm not familiar with mongoose and nestJS, Might I did a mistake in my entity?

```js
export type ProgramDocument = Program & Document

class Exercices {
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercice' })
  exercice: Exercice

  // others @Prop
  
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array})
  result: Array<ExerciceResult>
}

class ExerciceResult {
  @Prop()
  set: number;

  @Prop()
  kilogram: string;
}


@Schema()
export class Program {
  // others @Prop

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array})
  exercices: Array<Exercices>

}

export const ProgramSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Program)
```

Comment: Can you try the $push condition as "exercices.$.exercice".

Comment: doesn't work. I know how to add a object inside the exercices[] but seems like it's not possible to go deeper than that.

Comment: The problem is looking like inside of $and condition. { exercices: { $elemMatch : {exercice: exerciceId} } }. or try as {'exercices.exercice' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(exerciceId)}. Not inside of exercices object. Can you try one of these also.

Comment: I got this error : "plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot create field 'exercice' in element {exercices: [ { exercice: "6349563c2e0df123096b7feb", totalSet: 1, rest: "1" }, { exercice: "634956452e0df123096b7fed", totalSet: 2, rest: "2" } ]}"

The problem is when I add a exercice to a program (similar method than the one in the original post) it does save it as string and not "objectID(exerciceid)" in the database. Do you think the problem could be here ?

Comment: You may try to push value as ;  {result: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result)}

Comment: I did try and still not working. Is there any other way to update a value with mongoose ? Like loop over a object and push a value "manually" ?

Comment: I can only say that, we can add these objects in MongoDB Compass. Then update them easily. But pushing, we are trying to push a new field. Field is already declared inside of entity right ? Maybe not need to push. Just try to change the field's value. I know it is undefined but this maybe works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still not working. I did edit my question to add my entity. I think the problem could come from here. Because we did try everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to correct an update part,

- `$` references the object that matches in the subdocument condition/query, so it would be `"exercices.$.result"`

```js
let result = { set: 1, kilogram: "10" };

return this.programModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: "634c0777427df2a5adc17b4c",
    "exercices.exercice": "6349563c2e0df123096b7feb"
  },
  {
    $push: {
      "exercices.$.result": result
    }
  },
  { new: true }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PrnXOhhOjRb)

Comment: Great, it works perfectly. Thank you. 
How do you call the "$" in mongoose please ? I would like to find some documentations about it to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: It is a positional `$` operator, you can find this in [mongodb docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).